# Trouble implementing react-native-ssl-pinning with axios in React Native

Tags: react-native, security, ssl, cross-platform, certificate-pinning

I'm facing an issue while trying to implement SSL pinning using the react-native-ssl-pinning library in my React Native project. Specifically, I'm using React Native version 0.71.8.

Both react-native-ssl-pinning and react-native-cert-pinner are failing

I followed the documentation and installed the necessary dependencies. However it throws this error
[image]

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

1. npm install axios react-native-ssl-pinning
2. Import the necessary modules
3. Configure the SSL pinning certificates (RNSSLPinning.pinningCheck(certificates);)

Comment: Even this page is not helpful : https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#ssl-pinning

Comment: Can you share your code? How do you import `RNSSLPinning`?

Comment: import { RNSSLPinning } from 'react-native-ssl-pinning';

Comment: Maybe you need to run `react-native link`

Comment: react-native v0.71.8 does autolinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using this approach

1. For IoS  - using TrustKit
2. For Android - using OkHttp

**IOS**

1. Open your app's AppDelegate.m file
2. Import the TrustKit headers by adding the following line at the top of the file:

   #import <TrustKit/TrustKit.h>
3. Inside the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, configure TrustKit with your desired SSL pinning policy. For example:

   (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
   // Your other code...

   ```
   NSDictionary *trustKitConfig = @{
       kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @YES,
       kTSKPinnedDomains: @{
           @"example.com": @{
               kTSKPublicKeyHashes: @[
                   @"<public_key_hash_1>",
                   @"<public_key_hash_2>"
               ],
               kTSKEnforcePinning: @YES
           }
       }
   };

   [TrustKit initializeWithConfiguration:trustKitConfig];

   // Your other code...

   return YES;
   ```

   }

   Replace example.com with the hostname of the server you want to pin certificates for. <public_key_hash_1> and <public_key_hash_2> should be replaced with the SHA-256 hashes of the public keys from the server's SSL certificate. You can obtain these hashes using tools like OpenSSL.

   Note that you may have multiple pinned domains in the kTSKPinnedDomains dictionary if you want to pin certificates for multiple servers.
4. Build and run your React Native app